# How do I use AsyncTask like callbackfunction

Tags: android, android-asynctask, handler

I am in a case which can be seen below that I could not find any solution.

I am going to take result value from a webmethod and set it to a parameter then after some operation with it I will send it to another webmethod and it will used by another method, etc.  Here is what I want to do:

```
x = webMethodA();
y = webMethodB(x+3);
if(y){
z=10;
} else {
z=1000;
t = webMethodC(z);
```

I am using AsyncTask while calling webmethods because honeycomb does not support to call webservices on UI thread. I am geting the result value by onPostExecute but can not send to caller method back.

How do I overcome this problem?

```
setMethodName("GetTarih");
        KeyValuePair[] parameters = new KeyValuePair[2];
        parameters[0] = new KeyValuePair("Rep", "TEST001");
        parameters[1] = new KeyValuePair("Tarih", String.valueOf(Util.getOADateByToday()));
        CallSoap soap = new CallSoap(uri, soapAction, parameters);
        soap.setDataDownloadListener(new CallSoap.DataDownloadListener() {
            public void dataDownloadedSuccessfully(String data) {
                Log.e("aaaa",data);
                tarih = data;

            }
            public void dataDownloadFailed() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });

        soap.execute("");

       //I want to continue from this line with parameter named tarih.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "can not send to caller method back."?

Comment: The thing what I want to do is very simple. I am going to call a webmethod asynchronously and after get the result i will call another webmethod asynchronously again. and this goes on. The problem is, yes i can get the result from webmethod but I can not set result value to a parameter in UI Thread block. Main codes runs on UI and only webmethod callings runs on the background threads. I need to catch result value and pass it to a parameter which defines in UI block.

Comment: Ok, as kerubu said, check `Handler` class

Comment: it does not work with handler or I could not. Do you have any example to look like mine?

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to send messages/data/Bundles between threads take a look at [Message](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Message.html) and [Handler](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html) classes.

Your 'worker' thread will create a message to contain the result which will be sent to your UI thread.

When you create your Handler be sure you create it in the UI thread.